# Localize default context menu for link labels

Tags: c++, qt, windows

In my application I have some link labels, when I right click on them I get default OS context menu. It's only localized by Qt and this localization is not the same as my app localization. Is there a way to localize this menu? Thanks in advance.

Comment: How about using `tr()` ?

Comment: @sithereal

I know about `tr()`. I have my app already localized with it. But I need to localize default OS link label context menu. I don't code it, it manages by the system (OS) and localized by Qt. So how to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figure it out. So I have changed the code and now it loads default qt localization the same as my app localization.

**Link for qt documentation:** [How to create a multi language application](https://wiki.qt.io/How_to_create_a_multi_language_application)